# How to put sql inside sql

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

```
select 
    idRuler AS CURRID, 
    beginDate,
    endDate, 
    (SELECT SUM(TotalYearsAtService) 
     FROM Ruler WHERE idRuler=CURRID 
    ) AS PeriodTotal,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDstateddFK)),
    nameRuler AS Name 
FROM Ruler, Position, RulerToState
where Ruler.idRuler=IDrulerFK 
  and RulerToState.IDrulerdFK=Ruler.idRuler
GROUP BY nameRuler
```

It does not see CURRID inside (SELECT SUM(TotalYearsAtService) FROM Ruler WHERE idRuler=CURRID )

Comment: You should add your tables strucutures to see if we can help you get those SUM and COUNT from the main query.

Comment: Well, I found a solution: I created a field that is SQL computer.

Comment: Property NumberOfCoutries As %Integer [ Calculated, SqlComputeCode = { set n={idRuler} &sql(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDstateddFK) INTO :data  FROM RulerToState WHERE IDrulerdFK=:n) set {NumberOfCoutries}=data}, SqlComputed ];

Answer (score 3):

CURRID is an alias `idrules AS CURRID`, and in most cases you can't reference column aliases from inner queries or other places like group by's. While you can use table aliases, you can't use column aliases(in most cases) from within the same query.  This is primarily because the SELECT happens last.

Instead, use idrules in the inner query instead of CURRID, use table aliases to differentiate the inner and outer Rule table:

```
SELECT
    idRuler, 
    beginDate,
    endDate, 
    (SELECT SUM(TotalYearsAtService) 
     FROM Ruler r2 WHERE r1.idRuler = r2.idRuler
    ) AS PeriodTotal,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDstateddFK)),
    nameRuler AS Name 
FROM 
    Ruler r1, Position, RulerToState
WHERE
    Ruler.idRuler = IDrulerFK 
    AND RulerToState.IDrulerdFK = Ruler.idRuler
GROUP BY 
    nameRuler
```

Comment: Wow how'd you reformat *and* answer in that time?!  Specifically not column aliases in query at the same level, just in sub-queries under current level.

Comment: I cannot make idRuler=idRuler, it doest not make sence. I want idRuler_outer_query=idRuler_inner_sum. How to make it???

Comment: I have updated.  The outer query can have a table alias of r1 and the inner query a table alias of r2

Comment: There is a problem. I work with Cache and it do not allow Ruler r1 for some reason, so it show an sql error

Comment: @Tigran Try `Ruler as r1` instead. According to their documentation `Ruler r1` should work though as the `[AS]` in the grammar indicates it is optional, although maybe `r1` isn't a valid identifier in their system, see their link on valid identifiers: http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_from